# <script> inside response from Ajax.Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, prototypejs

is there a possibility to update innerHTML of element by Ajax.request that include  tags ?

```
<div><script type="text/javascript">javascript</script></div>
```

I would like to update content of div with code from top, not eval it.

Thanks for help.

EDIT:

Ok, so it's not as easy as should be.

I have main document that use Ajax.request that returns form, how to use prototype function from main document to manipulate data after form loads ?

EDIT:

This is button from Ajax.request response

```
<button onclick="sendForm();" id="submitForm" type="button" class="button"><span><?php echo $this->__('Send email') ?></span></button>
```

This if JS from main document

```
new Ajax.Request('/path/another_path/index',
      {
        method:'post',
        evalJS: true,
        onSuccess: function(transport){
            $('sendfriend').update(transport.responseText);
            var productSendtofriendForm = new VarienForm('product_sendtofriend_form');
        }
      });
```

And after clicking on this button i get "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: productSendtofriendForm"

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619668/executing-script-inside-div-retrieved-by-ajax

Comment: Protoype's `Ajax.Request` handles running your JavaScript upon DOM injection. Is there a problem with a piece of code not behaving as expected?

Comment: If i put <script> inside main document, and then run Ajax.request. Inside response there is a button with onclick="", when i click on it i can't call function that is in main document.

Comment: if the function inside the `<script>` tag is global, what you describe should work without issue. Show us the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sorry.

Only thing that i needed to do was to declare var productSendtofriendForm before Ajax.Request... needed to bo global one.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're updating the contents of an existing element you can both make use of [`Ajax.Updater`](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Updater/) and set it's `evalScripts` option. The script tag that gets inserted will be evaluated in the scope of the `Ajax.Updater`, meaning it can access functions that are global but not ones that are local to the script which started the update.

**Edit:**
You want a function contained in the script tag to exist in global scope. Instead of this:

```
function somefunc() { ...
```

You need to do it this way:

```
somefunc = function() { ...
```

And definitely don't use `var` as that prevents `somefunc` becoming a global variable. Later, when a button is clicked it's onclick event executes in global scope where `somefunc` now resides.

Comment: "I would like to update content of div with code from top, not eval it." <- Don't want to evalScripts, i need them as <script>

Answer (score 0):

Nice article [about experiments with innerHtml and script tags](http://poeticcode.wordpress.com/2007/10/03/innerhtml-and-script-tags/). It shouln't work but if SCRIPT tag has DEFER attribute then it will work under IE.