# How to run scripts for embedded objects in AJAX deep linked sites

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, embedding, deep-linking

I have an AJAX deep linked site. The basic structure is something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <!-- AJAX will change the content of this div tag -->
        <div id="ajax">
            ...
        </div>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

So the idea here is that AJAX according to the fragment value of the URL (`#query`) will appropriately populate the content of the `<div id="ajax">`.

Here is the issue. Consider this. User initially loads this page - (`#home`) and the following loads:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <!-- AJAX will change the content of this div tag -->
        <div id="ajax">
            <!-- content of the home page -->
            ...
        </div>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

After this, the user goes to the page `#query`. In order to load this page, AJAX will change the innerHTML of the  `<div id="ajax">` tag. Let's say that the content of the `#query` has an embedded object (in this example, an embedded video using FlowPlayer). After AJAX will be done, code will look something like this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <!-- AJAX will change the content of this div tag -->
        <div id="ajax">
            <!-- Flowplayer JavaScript component -->
            <script src="flowplayer-3.2.4.min.js"></script>
            <!-- The player container -->
            <div id="player" style="width:720px;height:480px;"></div>
            <!-- Player installation -->
            <script>
                flowplayer("player", "flowplayer.swf", {
                    clip: "video.mp4"
                });
            </script>
        </div>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

So here is the question, when I try to do this, the following script never runs and therefore the video never loads:

```
<script>
    flowplayer("player", "flowplayer.swf", {
        clip: "video.mp4"
    });
</script>
```

How can I fix this issue or what am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT** Progress report

I used to swap HTML content of `ajax` div tag by doing this:

```
document.getElementById("ajax").innerHTML = xmlhttprequest.responseText;
```

Now I have changed it to this:

```
var element = document.createElement("div");
element.setAttribute("id", "ajax");
element.innerHTML = xmlhttprequest.responseText;
toswap = document.getElementById("ajax");
toswap.parentNode.replaceChild(element, toswap);
```

This solved the issue in Firefox, so the `<script>` get triggered, however it still does not work in Chrome and IE.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does your ajax code look like - the code that fetches the content and adds the DOM fragment to the page?  Are you using a JavaScript library to help with the ajax stuff?

Comment: I am using SWFAddress for deep linking. Then I use XMLHttpRequest to get the content of the file I want to retrieve and then I do `document.getElementById("ajax").innerHTML = xmlhttprequest.responseText` to swap the html content.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers will not execute JavaScript that has been added to the DOM as text.  Take a look at this question which:

[Executing <script> inside <div> retrieved by AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619668/executing-script-inside-div-retrieved-by-ajax)