# JQuery .get doesnt execute Javascript

Tags: jquery, javascript, jquery-get

I am using JQuery .get method to retrieve some content from a webpage (page 1) and show it in a div in the main page. The problem is the content retrieved contains some javascript calls. The content is being displayed, but the **Javascript methods are not getting executed**. The .js file is being referenced across all the pages, so the availability of the js in the main is not a problem.

This is the code in the main page. URL of page 1 is given to the .get function:

```
$.get(url, function(response) {          
    var newContent = $(response).find("#right");      //Find the content section of the response
    var contentWrapper = $("#wrap");         //Find the content-wrapper where we are supposed to change the content.
    var oldContent = contentWrapper.find("#right");   //Find the old content which we should replace.

    oldContent.replaceWith(newContent);
});
```

This is the code in the #right (div) of Page 1

```
Some html tags...    
<p><script type="text/javascript">abc7();</script></p>
<p><script>s(30)</script></p>
Some html tags...
```

The functions abc7 and s are available in a .js (normal javascript file) that is being reference in the  section of all pages

The s(30) should display a  text field of size 30.

Comment: I found that this question is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619668/executing-script-inside-div-retrieved-by-ajax However, the solution presented there doesn't serve my purpose. First, I am not sure what function would be called in the response from Page1. So, I cant call those scripts from my ajax. Is there a way out ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inline JavaScript won't execute unless you run `eval()` on it. You can read more about that here:

- [Executing  inside  retrieved by AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619668/executing-script-inside-div-retrieved-by-ajax)
- [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)

An `eval()` solution could look something like this, **but I would consider it bad practice**:

```
$.get(url, function(response) {          
    var newContent = $(response).find("#right");      //Find the content section of the response
    var contentWrapper = $("#wrap");         //Find the content-wrapper where we are supposed to change the content.
    var oldContent = contentWrapper.find("#right");   //Find the old content which we should replace.

    oldContent.replaceWith(newContent);


    //Find all inline script tags in the new content and loop through them
    newContent.find("script").each(function() {
        var scriptContent = $(this).html(); //Grab the content of this tag
        eval(scriptContent); //Execute the content
    });
});
```

A better solution is to set a identifier/name on the `#right` tag and execute the code needed for that specific content.

Something like:

```
<div id="right" data-page-name="index">
    <!-- Content -->
</div>

<div id="right" data-page-name="about-us">
    <!-- Content -->
</div>
```

A simple solution that just passes the page name to a function that will execute the code depending on page would look something like this:

```
$.get(url, function(response) {          
    var newContent = $(response).find("#right");      //Find the content section of the response
    var contentWrapper = $("#wrap");         //Find the content-wrapper where we are supposed to change the content.
    var oldContent = contentWrapper.find("#right");   //Find the old content which we should replace.

    oldContent.replaceWith(newContent);

    var pageName = newContent.attr("data-page-name");

    pageSpecificActions(pageName);
});

function pageSpecificActions(pageName) {
    if (pageName == "index") {
        //Run the code for index page
    } else if (pageName == "about-us") {
        //Run the code for about us page.
    }   
};
```

This keeps the JavaScript code from being inline and doesn't use `eval()`. Even better would be to use events for when page content change, but this will be enough for now.

Comment: I tried the first method (looping through script tags) and for some reason it didn't work. I just used an alert('test'); for testing purpose, but it didn't pop out the alert box. Would it be possible to test it in the sample code that you've set up earlier at http://pushstate.staticloud.com/index.htm. In my case, I am calling an javascript (not jquery) function that is in an external file included in both the pages. Thanks

Comment: When I tried newContent.find("script").each(function() {alert("here");}); I see no alert boxes, which seems that The response is not retrieving the script tags, However, when I tried to find("p"), I see multiple alert boxes... The page1 contains <script> tags aswell.

Comment: It only looks for script tags inside the #right div, if you want to look at whole page1 you should do: response.find("script")...

Comment: Awesome answer. Those HTML5 data-attributes are sweet.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.load()` function instead of `.get()`. It automatically executes the scripts that are contained in the response.

Here is the documentation: [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: `load()` would append the contents of the response into the matched elements, not replace them, so it doesn't fully solve the problem.