# Use included files on javascript popup

Tags: javascript, include, popup

I've build a javascript pop-up on my site, but for some reason, this pop-up isn't using the included javascript files. How can I enforce the use of these?

I've included these files in my `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/form/jquery.validationEngine-nl.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/form/jquery.validationEngine.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

This is my HTML:

```
<input type="submit" class="modal" value="Shout !" />
```

And this is the JS that creates the pop-up:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    //Change these values to style your modal popup
    var align = 'center';       
    var top = 100;  
    var width = 500;    
    var padding = 10;
    var backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';    
    var source = 'includes/php/popup.php';  
    var borderColor = '#333333'; 
    var borderWeight = 4;   
    var borderRadius = 5;   
    var fadeOutTime = 300;  
    var disableColor = '#666666'; 
    var disableOpacity = 40; 
    var loadingImage = 'lib/release-0.0.1/loading.gif'; 

    //This method initialises the modal popup
    $(".modal").click(function() {
        modalPopup(align, top, width, padding, disableColor, disableOpacity, backgroundColor, borderColor, borderWeight, borderRadius, fadeOutTime, source, loadingImage);
    });

    //This method hides the popup when the escape key is pressed
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        closePopup(fadeOutTime);
        }
    });     
});
</script>
```

Even when I include the above JS-files in the `includes/php/popup.php`-file, they can't be used... What am I overseeing here?

The `modalPopup` function can be found [over here](http://chopapp.com/#qyuvnw7l).

Comment: what does `modalPopup` do? does that open an `iframe`, `div`, or an actual popup?

Comment: Here is the `modalPopup`-function: http://chopapp.com/#qyuvnw7l

Comment: are the `<script>` lines being added to the page at `document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML=page_request.responseText;` ?

Comment: i would take a look at - http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html - to see how to dynamically add the script files to the `<div />` modal

Comment: Not sure I get what you mean...

Comment: instead of just including the script tags, you will need to append the scripts themselves to the modal - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107847/executing-javascript-written-with-xmlhttprequest-that-contains-script-tags

Comment: That sounds like a lot of work... I was kind of hoping for an easy fix :-)

Comment: :) but if your modal is still part of the parent page, why don't you just add the script to the parent page to begin with?

Comment: That's what I did, no? The popup page and function are included on the parent page, right?