# Setting the this pointer while evaluating javascript

Tags: javascript, eval, this

I want to execute some javascript which is part of html I download through AJAX. After downloading I call `eval` to all script tags. Is there a way to manipulate the `this` pointer and let it point to something I define (e.g. the AJAX blob that was downloaded).
The reason why I need this is that I need some post-download processing on the `HTML` that was downloaded only. Now I do it by assigning an ID to the AJAX parent element and let the script do first a lookup (`getElementById`) of this element. This works as long as the ids are unique but that difficult to enforce in my case.

My current code looks like:

```
    if (element.children[i].tagName=="SCRIPT")
    {
        eval(element.children[i].innerHTML);
    }
```

I want the `this` pointer in `innerHTML` to point to `element`. Anyone?

Comment: I don't understand what is your question. "the `this` pointer in `innerHTML`" what does it means ? Can you put some simplified code (pseudo code?) to what you want to do (AJAX call, script evaluation etc), I think it would be more efficient than long text paragraphs :)

Comment: have more context?  not sure why you need the 'this' or 'eval'.  Just including the <script> tag not work?

Comment: (1) I don't see why you need to `eval` anything. Append the ajax'd fragment to somewhere in the DOM and the browser will take care of this for you. (2) Why do you want to make `this` a reference to a `<script>` tag? Does the JS depend on it? The entire thing is very smelly to me.

Comment: If you download AJAX elements containing `<script>` elements, they won't be executed by assigning it to an existing `element.innerHTML`! See for example [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619668/executing-script-inside-div-retrieved-by-ajax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [`Function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). Note that primitives (`42`, `true`, `"foo"`) will be boxed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I had a quick look at `apply` and `call` but don't see how to use it in my case. I extended my question with my current code. Can you suggest how to change this code? Thx!

Comment: Okay, I found the solution! I first try calling `eval.apply(element,element.children[i].innerHTML)` but this didn't work. Now I changed the code to `var func = new Function(element.children[i].innerHTML); func.apply(element);` and this works fine!

Comment: That's exactly what I was going to suggest. See my comment on your question, however — this is all very very smelly.

Answer (score 0):

I think cleaner.

```
if (element.children[i].tagName=="SCRIPT")
{
    eval.call(element, element.children[i].innerHTML);
}
```