# Googlemaps V3 and Ajax load() menu

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-maps

Well I've been working on this for a while, but i still have no response..

What I am trying to do, is load a googlemap with an ajax no refreshing menu. So here is the main page which loads all of the menu pages, i'm gonna call main.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=false">
</script>

<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="page_main">Main</a></li>
    <li><a href="page_weather">Weather</a></li>
    </ul>


    <div id="content"></div>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //initial
        $('#content').load('menu/page_main.php');

        //handle menu clicks
        $('ul#nav li a').click(function() {
            var page = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#content').load('menu/' + page + '.php');
            return false;

        });

    });

    </script>
```

And here is the page with the map, let's call page_weather.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=false">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-15.869167, -47.920834),
          zoom: 3,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);
        }



      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<h1>Principal</h1>

</br>
</br>

<body onLoad="initialize()">

<div id="map_canvas" style="width:800; height:400;"></div>
```

When page_weather.php is loaded directly in the browser, the map loads properly, but when the page is loaded using the ajax no refreshing menu, i only get a 800x400 white box.

How i can fix this?

Already tryed:

[Executing <script> inside <div> retrieved by AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619668/executing-script-inside-div-retrieved-by-ajax)

[Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery will in fact take care of executing `<script>` tags for you via `jQuery.load()`. Your problem lies in the fact you are using the `window.load` event to initialize the google map. This event will never be triggered if you inject this script into the document after the initial window load.

I'd have a better workaround if google maps didn't insist on a `window.load` event rather than the dom ready event like most libraries. But since your `initialize()` function is a global function, you should simply be able to change your `load` call to this:

```
$('#content').load('menu/page_main.php', function () {
    initialize();
});
```

By the way, remove the `onLoad="initialize()"`. You already have the `window.load` event being set by the `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` line.

Answer (score 0):

The event is generated before function and it does not recognize, you put this code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); 

});
```