# function calling from other file (ajax)

Tags: javascript, function

I want to know if it is possible to the the following thing: 
I  load a div dynamically in ajax.  In that div, I also have a javscript function (MyChildFuction()).  On my principal page (the one from which I've loaded my dynamic div), I also have a function (MotherFunction()).
I want to call MyChildFunction from MotherFunction. 
 It this possible?  Thank you!

Comment: Answered previously here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4620099/877472.

Comment: @Teeg: It's not an exact match to that.  The simple answer is: Yes. It's possible.  Which leads to the question: what part, exactly, does the OP have a problem doing?  Code samples go a long way to showing what you've done so far and will help people point you in the right direction.