# Script not showing on html document loaded via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Here is my problem:

I have a script my nimbit store gave to me, I installed it on my store.html and it's working, my problem is when store.html is loaded through ajax the script - it is not showing.

Help please! Go easy on me I am not a professional developer or programmer!
Thanks a lot in advance.

This is the  script my nimbit store gave to me:

```
<script src="http://www.nimbitmusic.com/tags/javascript/artists/theit_boy.1/store/"></script>
```

I have installed it on my store.html

[1]: http://theitboymusic.com/store.html and it works, but if i loaded through the store button on my [index.html][1] is disappearing.

Thanks in advance

```
<!-- ############ ajax content (This content will be loaded by ajax) ############ -->
<div id="ajax-content" class="page-container">

    <!-- ############ container ############ -->
    <div class="container clearfix">

        <!-- ############ content header ############ -->
        <header class="content-header">
            <h1 class="content-title">STORE</h1>
            <span class="sub-heading">Purchase The IT_Boy Music</span>

            <hr class="content-line">
        </header>
        <!-- /content header -->

      <script src="http://www.nimbitmusic.com/tags/javascript/artists/theit_boy.1/store/"></script>
```

my custom.js code:

```
    // Custom pages
    // create a new instance of the plugin
    var custom_page = new $.PageLoader($('.page-by-ajax'), { 
        container_class : 'custom-container',
        top_offset : -settings.nav_height,
        deeplinking : true,
        debug : false,
        load_from_hash : true,
        load_start : function(){
            // I get fired when the ajax is starting load content

            // Show preloader
            NProgress.start();
        },
        load_end : function(e){
            // I get fired when the ajax is ending load content
            // Init scripts
            scripts(e);

            // Hide preloader
            NProgress.done();

        },
        close : function(){

            // Scroll to portfolio filter
            $.scrollTo('#custom-page', 400,{offset: {top:-settings.nav_height, left:0}});
        }
    });


})();
```

});

and in my index.html

```
 <li>
                        <a href="store.html" class="page-by-ajax" data-ajax-options='{"target" :"#custom-page"}'>STORE</a
                            </li>
```

Comment: Its okay but you have to post code which caused or maybe the cause of the error.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619668/executing-script-inside-div-retrieved-by-ajax

Comment: Ok we are almost there... Where is your `scripts` function (called in the `load_end` callback) ?

Comment: This is all about `scripts(e);`

Comment: brewal could you explain that to me please?

Comment: You should post the code of the `scripts` function. It is here to load script after a page has been loaded with ajax. So maybe you have to register your script somewhere in order to make this function load it

Answer (score 0):

Your "Content-Type" of "Response Header" is "text/plain", but it should be "text/html"

Comment: I am not sure if I did it right but it is not working   Thanks anyway!!! could you be a little more specific? on store.html?