# Fancybox inline html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

Now i am using construction like this

```
$.post(
    location.href,
    {
        adverts: []
    },
    function (html) {
        $.fancybox({
            'content': html,
            'type': 'html',
            'padding': 0
        });
    }
);
```

And everything works fine, if html is only html, but if i add javascript to html,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    alert('text');

</script>
```

attempt to open fancybox is crashing with **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input**

Please notice, in my case i can't use 'href' instead of 'content' for fancybox.

**Update**

```
<script>

    alert('');

</script>
```

Fixed the problem, just removed **type="text/javascript"** part :)

**Update:**

Any type of quotes breaking fancybox opening ;)

Comment: I guess it should be a problem with the parse of fancybox, good to know it :)

Comment: I think this is more ajax content than inline content. Here there are some interesting reading when inserting scripts via ajax http://stackoverflow.com/q/4619668/1055987 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1197575/1055987

Comment: If you have solved your problem, I think you should answer your own question (and accept the answer) so that it is not shown among "unanswered".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    alert('');
</script>
```

Fixed the problem, just removed **type="text/javascript"** part.

**Update:**

Any type of quotes breaking fancybox opening.