# Getting data from jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make an AJAX filter for car list and I got stuck in the last stage. I have two files, index.php and filter.php.

In *index.php* I have form with drop-down lists and sliders. Code for sending the form is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#send").click(function(){

            var salon=$("#salon-list").val();
            var make=$("#make-list").val();
            var model=$("#model-list").val();
            var cenaLow=$("#cenaLow").val();
            var cenaHigh=$("#cenaHigh").val();
            var tachometrLow=$("#tachometrLow").val();
            var tachometrHigh=$("#tachometrHigh").val();
            var palivo=$("#palivo-list").val();
            var karoserie=$("#karoserie-list").val();
            var prevodovka=$("#prevodovka-list").val();
            var pohon=$("#pohon-list").val();
            var barva=$("#barva-list").val();
            var dvere=$("#dvere-list").val();
            var objem=$("#objem-list").val();
            var stav=$("#stav-list").val();


            $.ajax({
                type:"post",
                url:"filter.php",
                data:"salon="+salon+"&make="+make+"&model="+model+"&cenaLow="+cenaLow+"&cenaHigh="+cenaHigh
                +"&tachometrLow="+tachometrLow+"&tachometrHigh="+tachometrHigh+"&palivo="+palivo+"&karoserie" +
                "="+karoserie+"&prevodovka="+prevodovka+"&pohon="+pohon+"&barva="+barva+"&dveře="+dvere+"&objem" +
                "="+objem+"&stav="+stav,
                success:function(data){
                    $("#result").html(data);
                }

            });

        });
    });
```

In the *filter.php* file I get the data from $_POST and then I search through database. After that I want to echo results into #result div but it does not work. Any echo statement doesn't work, variables I want to list aren't empty, I checked.

```
echo 'iAmHere'; /*just checking*/

$post["salon"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["salon"]);
$post["make"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["make"]);
$post["model"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["model"]);
$post["cenaLow"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["cenaLow"]);
$post["cenaHigh"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["cenaHigh"]);
$post["rokLow"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["rokLow"]);
$post["rokHigh"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["rokHigh"]);
$post["tachometrLow"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["tachometrLow"]);
$post["tachometrHigh"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["tachometrHigh"]);
$post["palivo"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["palivo"]);
$post["karoserie"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["karoserie"]);
$post["prevodovka"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["prevodovka"]);
$post["pohon"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["pohon"]);
$post["barva"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["barva"]);
$post["dvere"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["dvere"]);
$post["objem"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["objem"]);
$post["stav"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["stav"]);

echo '<p class="make">'.$post["make"].'</p>'; /*does not work*/


echo "<script>window.alert('".$_POST["make"]."');</script>";  /*another checking, this works*/
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: Please include the code you're using to respond to the AJAX call server side.

Comment: what is the output of print_r($_POST) ?

Comment: No error in console.

Output of print_r($_POST) is:
 Array ( [salon] => 0 [make] => 149 [model] => [cenaLow] => 50000 [cenaHigh] => 300000 [rokLow] => 1998 [rokHigh] => 2009 [tachometrLow] => 40000 [tachometrHigh] => 210000 [palivo] => [karoserie] => [prevodovka] => [pohon] => [barva] => [dvere] => [objem] => [stav] => [send] => Odeslat )   
(it doesn't list print_r neither, I had to use it as form action to get it)

Comment: Could you please add `error` callback to your `$.ajax` to check if there are any errors occuring during ajax request? `error : function() { console.log('ajax request failed!'); }`

Comment: 1) use object as ajax data-property value instead raw text. Its more readable
2) add error callback as suggested above, also debug data with console.log(data) in success callback too
3) Look into browser network-debugging panel to see data was sent and received. So you can understand what you did wrong.
4) Use JSON-data instead raw html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#send").click(function(){
 var salon=$("#salon-list").val();
            var make=$("#make-list").val();
            var model=$("#model-list").val();
            var cenaLow=$("#cenaLow").val();
            var cenaHigh=$("#cenaHigh").val();
            var tachometrLow=$("#tachometrLow").val();
            var tachometrHigh=$("#tachometrHigh").val();
            var palivo=$("#palivo-list").val();
            var karoserie=$("#karoserie-list").val();
            var prevodovka=$("#prevodovka-list").val();
            var pohon=$("#pohon-list").val();
            var barva=$("#barva-list").val();
            var dvere=$("#dvere-list").val();
            var objem=$("#objem-list").val();
            var stav=$("#stav-list").val();

 var data= {
            make: make,
            model: model,
            cenaLow: cenaLow,
            cenaHigh: cenaHigh,
            tachometrLow: tachometrLow,
            tachometrHigh: tachometrHigh,
            palivo: palivo,
            karoserie: karoserie,
            prevodovka: prevodovka,
            pohon: pohon,
            barva: barva,
            objem: objem,
            stav : stav
        };


            $.ajax({
                type:"post",
                url:"filter.php",
                data:data,
                success:function(data){
                    $("#result").html(data);
                }

            });

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619668/executing-script-inside-div-retrieved-by-ajax):

> JavaScript inserted as DOM text will not execute.

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml) says:

> You have to use [eval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) to execute any script code that you've
>   inserted as DOM text.

So you can try an alternate approach to test your code (though I've not tested).

**In filter.php:**

```
<?php
$post["salon"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["salon"]);
$post["make"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["make"]);
$post["model"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["model"]);
$post["cenaLow"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["cenaLow"]);
$post["cenaHigh"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["cenaHigh"]);
$post["rokLow"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["rokLow"]);
$post["rokHigh"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["rokHigh"]);
$post["tachometrLow"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["tachometrLow"]);
$post["tachometrHigh"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["tachometrHigh"]);
$post["palivo"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["palivo"]);
$post["karoserie"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["karoserie"]);
$post["prevodovka"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["prevodovka"]);
$post["pohon"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["pohon"]);
$post["barva"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["barva"]);
$post["dvere"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["dvere"]);
$post["objem"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["objem"]);
$post["stav"] = htmlspecialchars($_POST["stav"]);

echo $post["make"];
```

**In index.php:**

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success:function(res){
       $("#result").html(res);
       alert(res);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
die('<p class="make">'.$post["make"].'</p>');
```

or

```
echo '<p class="make">'.$post["make"].'</p>';exit;
```

instead of

```
echo '<p class="make">'.$post["make"].'</p>'; /*does not work*/


echo "<script>window.alert('".$_POST["make"]."');</script>";  /*another checking, this works*/
```

It does not work without an exit. I do not know why but it should do the trick. Also, your code has a lot of room for improvement. Do keep looking for better ways to enhance your skills!! Enjoy!!