# Executing javascript in AJAX with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I'm curious about the effects of the following scenarios:

Suppose I'm defining a jQuery click event, for example

```
$(function()
{
    $('.someElement').click(function() { /*do something*/ };
};
```

which gets loaded in some arbitrary `HTTP GET` request.
But this `.someElement` does not initially exists in the DOM when requesting.

Now if I also have an asynchronous AJAX call which inserts some piece of `html` that *does* have this `.someElement` defined, for example

```
$.ajax(
{
    //options omitted for readability
    success: function(responseData)
    {
        $('#elementToInsert').html(responseData);
    }
});
```

loads and inserts `<div class="someElement"></div>` into the page.
It seems that when clicking on the `.someElement` element, the script in the jQuery click event gets executed.

It somehow bugs me that this works. Would someone explain me why this works?

Also imagine the next scenario:

As in the previous example, I'm requesting the same arbitrary `HTTP GET`. But in this request, the click event is **not** included. The same `ajax` call *is* included though.

Now the html in the `responseData` looks like this

```
<div class="someElement"></div>
<script>
    $(function()
    {
        $('.someElement').click(function() { /*do something*/ };
    };
</script>
```

When I click on `.someElement`, I get the exact same behavior as in the first scenario. This bugs me even more, so could someone also explain to me why this works?

Some notes:

- The `responseData` that gets inserted into the DOM, would be somewhere **before** the jQuery library.
- I don't think it should matter which server side framework is used, but in my case it would be ASP.NET MVC 5.
- These scenarios are tested in the most recent versions of the following browsers: IE, Firefox, Chrome.

To summarize my question: *How is it possible that the mentioned scenarios works (e.g. that the jQuery gets executed)?*

**P.S.** The funny thing is that in the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619668/executing-script-inside-div-retrieved-by-ajax), it's explained that

> JavaScript inserted as DOM text will not execute.

while in my case it *is* executed.
It also refers to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml) that explains that `eval()` has to be called in order to execute javascript.
Also [this article](http://technify.me/user-experience/javascript/executing-javascript-in-an-ajax-response/) explains the opposite of my scenarios and mentions the use of `eval()`.

Comment: Try this instead of using the `click`. `$('.someElement').on('click', function() { /*do something*/ };`

Comment: @pmahomme did you even read the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is the expected behaviour.

If you load HTML containing script tags, those script tags will be executed in some cases.
For instance if the dataType is `html` or the `Content-type` header is set in such a way on the server that jQuery parses it as HTML, the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) states

> "html": Returns HTML as plain text; **included script tags are evaluated**
>   when inserted in the DOM.

In many cases, where the dataType is not set, and there are no headers or mime type for jQuery to infer the type of data loaded, the default will most likely be `text`, where no parsing will be done, and no scripts will be executed

> "text": A plain text string

Even jQuery `load()` has this behaviour now, and the documentation explicitly states that

> When calling `.load()` using a URL without a suffixed selector
>   expression, the content is passed to `.html()` *prior to scripts being
>   removed*. **This executes the script blocks before they are discarded**.

So yes, jQuery will execute script blocks in HTML content gotten with ajax calls

Comment: IIS Express is used in my test cases (with ASP.NET MVC 5 as mentioned) and while inspecting the network tab in the developer tabs of the browser, the content type is `text/html`. So because the server adds the `text/html` in the response header's content-type, the browser can understand and evaluate the javascript?

Comment: Yes, because the correct content type is set, jQuery is able to infer the data type, even when the `dataType` option is not set, and parse the content as HTML and execute the script tags.