# Javascript <script> included within Ajax HTML responseText (inserted with innerHTML) - how to execute functions

Tags: javascript, ajax, innerhtml

When obtaining HTML from AJAX and inserting it into the page I have found that any script elements do not appear to run.  It transpires that any scripts inserted via innerHTML do not execute.

Calling a function in such a script returns

> ReferenceError: x is not defined

I have tried various ways of trying to run these script elements but none that actually work successfully.  Closest I have found is below:

This reads through each inserted script tag and runs eval() on it, which does actually run any plain javascript code however the functions parsed do not become persistent and cannot be called at a later time.

Edit1:
Better example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<script>
 function fixInsertedHtml(eScript) {
  var codes = eScript.getElementsByTagName("script");
  for(var i=0;i<codes.length;i++) {
   eval(codes[i].text);
  }  
 } 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1" >div1</div>

<script>
 var insertHTML = "Inserted HTML \
  <script> \
   alert('In inserted script'); \
   test(1); \
   function test(val) { console.log('test'+val); } \
   test(2); \
  <\/script>";
 div1.innerHTML = insertHTML;
 console.log("Before fixInsertedHtml");
 fixInsertedHtml(div1);
 test(3); // ReferenceError test is not defined
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing <script> inside <div> retrieved by AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619668/executing-script-inside-div-retrieved-by-ajax)

Comment: Can you show an example that you think should work?