# Fetching data through ajax in html file

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have an HTML page that fetches data through AJAX. The file that is fecthed is a PHP file with its own javascript function.  While the PHP file is fetched by the HTML file through AJAX, the javascript function in the PHP does not  work.

Can any one please explain to me why this is the case? I am stuck.

Comment: without any code and more details it's kind of hard to help you here!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing <script> inside <div> retrieved by AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619668/executing-script-inside-div-retrieved-by-ajax)

Comment: show demo so we can know exctly

Comment: If it's a full page you're fetching, isn't it easier to just use a hyperlink? Or if it isn't a full page, why is it php instead of xml or json or some other data format?