# Attach dynamically loaded javascript event handler to dynamically loaded HTML

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I have a site which loads content through AJAX. I need to attach onclick handler to some div which was dynamically loaded. It works fine if my event handler is already defined in my main javascript file (whether I attach it through markup via attribute `onclick="myFunc"` on by more pedantic `addEventListener` ).

However, I would like this event handler to be defined in a `<script>` tag of the **dynamically loaded** content. Then it doesn't work, whether `<script>function myHandler(){}</script>` is before or after the `<div onclick='myHandler();'>`.

I tried to attach it at the end of the XmlHttpRequest:

```
contentDiv.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
var handlerName = getItFrom(xhr.responseText); 
var clickFn = window[handlerName];
loadedDiv.addEventListener('click', clickFn);
```

Doesn't work neither: `handlerName` is correct, but `clickFn` remains undefined...

I prefer a pure js answer but jquery is ok if I can easily translate it.

Comment: Where's `window[handlerName]` been defined and where's `loadedDiv`  been defined?

Comment: no one codes front end this way anymore :( but if you have to then assign an id to <div> and then handle the on load event by attaching an event listener to your html element... or you can pick up webpack and react and make your life easier

Comment: @Kosh `window[handlerName]` is just a way to get a function object by its name. If handlerName was defined in the main javascript that would work. `loadedDiv` is of course given through a `document.getElementById`. I just skipped those details as they are irrelevant.

Comment: @Dmitry it is exactly the same problem: if the onload event listener is sent through the dynamic content, it doesn't work.

Comment: @James Thanks! I missed this post. So, it doesn't work, period. It seems the only solution is to load the script as a file but cannot be included in the innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

If `getItFrom(xhr.responseText);` returns a function defined in the global scope try to add quotes like this:

`var clickFn = window['handlerName'];`

Because console says:

```
var luck = function(){}; window[luck];
> undefined
var luck = function(){}; window['luck'];
> function luck()
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. However handlerName is already a string. Anyway it is not feasible as indiacted in this answer: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619668/executing-script-inside-div-retrieved-by-ajax unless getting the script from an external link.

Comment: Could you please let me know what that string contains?

Answer (score 0):

It's doable if you're willing to use jQuery, here I assign an event handler from a script tag of a html string.  A couple of things, the parameter you pass into `.html` has to be a jQuery object of your string, and you'll need to replace `</script>` with `<\/script>` within the string (could use `.replace`).

```js
$('#content').html($("<span>before</span><script>$('#testo').click(function () { alert('infunc');});<\/script><span>after</span>"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='content'></div>
<button id='testo'>Click</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe internally jQuery is grabing the script text and using eval (?). Anyway I can't use this solution. Finally I decided to do what I already do: predefining all the scripts in my main javascript file.