# Ajax PHP script not running

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want a PHP script to run on form submit and use Ajax to stop the page refreshing.

The JavaScript code successfully reaches the .done method and I put a console.log into the first line of my php script which doesn't seem to be getting triggered.

JS

```js
$('.enquire-form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $this = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "post.php",
    data: $this.serialize()
  }).done(function(data) {
    alert("done");
  }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus);
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
  });
});
```

PHP (originally it was console.log but have changed based on suggestions)

```
echo "hello world";
```

Folder directory (enquiry.html has the form in it)
[image]

Thanks :)

Comment: `echo "<script>console.log("hi");</script>";` is a syntax error.

Comment: Your PHP should be `echo "<script>console.log('hi');</script>";`

Comment: @u_mulder Thanks (woops) but still it doesn't work after updating  http://prntscr.com/fwbals

Comment: And there's no need to return javascript, as you're already in a javascript.

Comment: See above @MilanChheda

Comment: why you want to return js script from php .

Comment: @ArunKillu It was as a test, the actual script is for recaptcha v2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless something has changed, you can't execute JS that has been returned from an AJAX call. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619668/executing-script-inside-div-retrieved-by-ajax).

Make sure you are attempting to access the returned data via the `data` var inside your done function.

Comment: I changed it to echo "hello world" with no luck.

Comment: Is your PHP file running on a server?

Comment: uWamp local server

Comment: Try to call the PHP file via curl and see what happens. Or even call it from the command line with `php [your-file].php`. FWIW, your example code doesn't open with <?php

Comment: Also, your AJAX function only alerts "Done". If you want to see what was returned, you need to alert or console.log 'data'.

Comment: Woops,  I added that in - I must have forgot to re-add it in; still no luck though :/. How do I call it from the command line? Just enter the path in?

Comment: Data does contain "hello world". As it was an echo normally I'd expect it to be on the page, does using Ajax change this? + can you please update ur post with what was wrong so i can mark it as correct

Comment: AJAX does change things. Since there is no page load, your only access to the output of the PHP script is through the `data` variable in your `.done` promise.

Comment: Thanks, think I'll spend more time learning Ajax later on today, it looks like I need to learn more about it in general :).