# How to Run <body onLoad=""> of php page on synchronised data-async-load call in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

As I've successfully open a `xy.php` page in `div id="portfolio"` of the working `abc.php` page  without redirection. But the problem arose is that I think it is a synchronized call that is why when the `xy.php` page open in a `div id="portfolio"` than its `<body onload="">` onload function does not call because this `xy.php` page is opened using synchronised method not redirect. So, On Synchronised call how to run the functions which is present inside onload="". Any Suggestions ? ?  ?

Here is my working [JS Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ta0a5821/5/)

I'm calling the next page on `

```
                <li><a data-async-load="xy.php"></a></li>` tag
```

Comment: Inline script is not called using .load - you need to not have onload event handlers on tags and instead extract them and call them in the parent document - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619668/executing-script-inside-div-retrieved-by-ajax

Comment: As mplungjan said, you can't have embedded inline scripts auto execute this way. You should instead replicate their behaviour in the success option of the .load() method you're using to load the page.

Comment: I did not get it. I just want to run `xy.php`  <body onLoad=""> functions that is it. How do I get this approach ? any example

Comment: Any example @delinear

Comment: I just want to call the functions on onload method when the page is open

Comment: @mplungjan so where should i've to do change  ?? ? ? I'm searching but didn't get anything

Comment: if you do not want to move the JS code from xy.php as you should, then you need to load the page, find the script tags that contains the function called in the onload and eval it

Answer (score 0):

Ok I Did it!!!!
 The functions `<body onload="myfuna();myfunb();">` which are called on loading or redirecting or refereshing the page is know called by  using JQuery and it works when you are loading your page by synchronisation data-async-load. Here is the code

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
 myfuna();
 myfunb();
 });
 if (document.readyState == 'complete')
 doOnLoad();

 $(window).bind("load", doOnLoad); 

 </script>
```