# PHP & JS - append html and scripts on page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using an ajax call to append a MVC partial view with some styles sheets and script files to my php page.

However it is not appending de `<script>` tags. I already checked my HTTP request on the network and it really brings those tags.

**My code:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:63322/MyController/MyAction', //external url project
    data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    crossDomain: true,
    processdata: true,
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*"
    },
    success: function(result){  
        $(".pageContainer").html(result);           
    },
    error: function(er){ alert('Error'); }
});
```

On ajax success function I already tried:

- to use `$(".pageContainer").empty().append(result)`
- to separate the script tags and add to `<head>` like this:

> ```
>  var elems = $(result);
>  var scripts = $.grep(elems, function(e){ 
>       try{ 
>            return e.tagName.toLowerCase() == "script";
>       }catch(er){ return false; }
>   });
>  var remainElems = $.grep(elems, function(e){ 
>       try{ 
>            return e.tagName.toLowerCase() != "script";
>       }catch(er){ return false; }
>  });
>
>  $.each(scripts, function(){ $('head')[0].appendChild(this); });
>  $(".pageContainer").append(remainElems);
> ```

- to give some time before appending with `setTimeout(function(){ $(".pageContainer").html(result); }, 1000);`
- to change `<script>` tags to `<link type="text/javascript" src="http://someurl.com" rel="tag"/>` and it was appended but the code wasn't executed

But nothing works.

What is wrong? What I'm missing?

My PHP page uses jquery-1.8.3 and jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom. This is the problem?

**NOTE:**

My question is very different from that on: [Executing  inside  retrieved by AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619668/executing-script-inside-div-retrieved-by-ajax)

If you read both you will see they are very different. I already readed what and noticed that.

Comment: The problem is, as have many others encountered before you, that appending a `<script>` does not automatically run it. The proper way is to put all JS code in your main script, then run appropriate functions after getting new content. The other way is to wrap the code in the tags in a function and call it after appending the script.

Comment: @ChrisG if you read all my question you will see I already tried that but that doesn't worked.

Comment: @ChrisG yes, was what I said. And yes, I already sayed `I already checked my HTTP request on the network and it really brings those tags`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I don't know why but seems jquery-1.8.3 don't performs the insertion of the `<script>` tags to the html code dynamically.

I changed

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

and now it works.