# Use AJAX to avoid Google Maps charges and show maps only when someone clicks a button

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

Effective July 16, 2018, the Google Maps API is not entirely free anymore. `As of July 16, 2018, to continue to use the Google Maps Platform APIs, you must enable billing on each of your projects.` (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage-and-billing).

My problem is that after a week using the new Google Maps API with the corresponding key and billing information that Google requires, I have started to see pretty insane charges for my usage. That is good because it means that I have a significant traffic to my website, and I should not be complaining about that specifically. The problem is that probably the vast majority of my visitors do not even see/use the maps all the time, and I am still being charged as soon as they load a page that has a map on it.

My idea is to not show the map by default and have a link that says "Show map" so that I only show the map to people who are really interested in seeing the map. Then I want to make an AJAX request to the Google Maps API. I know and recognize that this is a way to circumvent payments, but I think it is fair game because I only want to be charged for usage when my visitors really see/interact with the Google Maps feature, not as soon as they load pages on my website. Would Google allow me to do that or would it be considered cheating? Take a look at the code at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial. My idea is to call this block of code with an AJAX request when visitors click a "Show map" button, to try to reduce charges:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
</script>
```

**UPDATE 1**: Reading [Executing <script> inside <div> retrieved by AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619668/executing-script-inside-div-retrieved-by-ajax), the answer by Chocula says that

> JavaScript inserted as DOM text will not execute.

That makes sense. Thinking about the technical implications of trying what I am asking in this question, I doubt it would work considering that JavaScript does not execute when it is inserted as DOM text. The problem is that I would be generating the `<script>...</script>` portion with AJAX, inserted as DOM text and that would not execute. If I inserted it as soon as the page loads, then I would be immediately charged regardless of whether or not I actually show the map by displaying the `<div id="map"></div>` portion of code. It sounds like an interesting way to circumvent payments for all those cases when people do not even see the map or are not interested in seeing it or interacting with it, fair game, but I do not think I could do this with AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could perhaps do would be to use a placeholder image that suggests a map, load the Javascript but not invoke the map functions ( usually called via `initMap` in Google's examples )

The example below is overly exaggerated but gives an idea of what I am suggesting perhaps. I was monitoring the map loads via the Google console - simply loading the page did not increment the counter but once the map was clicked and the map properly invoked I found the quota counter rising.

Perhaps this might be of use...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Load a map on demand</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height:100vh;
            width:100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        body{
            display:flex;
            align-items:center;
            justify-content:center;
            background:whitesmoke;
        }
        #map {
            height:90vh;
            width:90%;
            margin:auto;
            border:3px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
        }
        .staticmap{
            background-image:url(/images/maps/static-map-scotland.jpg);
            background-position:top left;
            background-size:cover;
            display:flex;
            align-items:center;
            justify-content:center;
            border:3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25)!important;
        }
        /* use a pseudo element class to display a message */
        .staticmap:after{
            content:attr(data-info);
            font-size:3rem;
            color:red;
            width:100%;
            display:block;
            text-align:center;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

            let map=document.getElementById('map');

            const initMap=function() {
                var default_location = {
                    lat:56.646577,
                    lng:-2.888609
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map( map, {
                    zoom: 10, 
                    center: default_location,
                    mapTypeId:'roadmap',
                    mapTypeControlOptions: { style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU }
                });
                let options={
                    position:default_location,
                    map:map,
                    icon:'//maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-pushpin.png',
                    title:'Default location'
                }

                marker = new google.maps.Marker( options );
            }


            /* let the user know to click the map if they need to use it's features */
            map.onmouseover=function(){ 
                this.dataset.info='Click on the map to load';
            };
            map.onmouseout=function(){
                this.dataset.info='';
            };

            document.querySelector('.staticmap').onclick=function(){
                if( confirm('Would you like to load the proper map?') ){

                    /* invoke the map fully */
                    initMap();

                    /* remove class that presented static image etc */
                    this.classList.remove('staticmap');
                }
            }
        },false);
    </script>






    <!--
        Rather than have the map initialisation run as a callback ( via the querystring parameter `callback=initMap` )
        or inline as a pageload function ( ie: `onload=initMap` etc ) do nothing at this stage.
    -->
    <script async defer src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='map' class='staticmap' data-info=''></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Example 1: Page loads to display static image that suggests a map is available]
[image: Clicking the map to invoke the actual map]
[image: The actual map is now loaded...]
[image: Google Console]