# Can a file that is called by ajax call another file using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need a PHP file that is called by ajax to call another file by AJAX when the value of a select changes.

Example:
-File1.php
Show header and more.
Makes an Ajax call to file2.php

File2.php
Shows services with editable fields with their data.
Makes an Ajax call to file3.php when I change the value of a specific select

File3.php
Save the data of that editable field

I mention this because it doesn't work from File1.php, but if I do it directly from File2.php it does work.It seems that the javascript in File2.php does not work if called via AJAX.

Comment: Whatever the response to an AJAX request is, needs to be handled by _you_, in your coding. Even if you return HTML code and insert that into your document, any JavaScript it contains will not get executed automatically, you would have to undertake additional steps for that. But the whole description of the issue here so far _screams_ that this should be structured differently to begin with.

Comment: _"Makes an Ajax call to file3.php"_ - "files" don't make AJAX requests, and AJAX requests are not made _to_ "files" either. The browser makes the request, when instructed to do so by some JS code, and it makes it towards a _URL_, not a "file". (URLs _might_ correspond with the file structure on the server in parts, but they don't have to.) So stop thinking "in" files so much here, and instead start approaching this by pinning down the correct client-side logic first.

Comment: *It seems that the javascript in File2.php does not work if called via AJAX* - this is your issue - your ajax call to load "file2" needs to also *initiate* any scripts - they're not loaded automatically.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619668/executing-script-injected-by-innerhtml-after-ajax-call) for a *possbile* solution to get "file2" to execute js.  (edit: it uses `eval` so use at your own risk) - better solution is to move the js out of the php into js files and load *them*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because AJAX runs in the browser using JS.

If you send a HTTP request via AJAX to execute a PHP script then, as always it runs on the server. But in the AJAX scenario, even if that PHP script contains some JS, that JS is never loaded into a browser (because AJAX causes an asynchronous background request, rather than a page load into a browser tab), so of course the JS code would never run.

Note that even if you then insert the the whole of File2's output into the DOM using JS when your first AJAX call ends, that won't automatically cause the JS within it to be evaluated and executed - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619668/executing-script-injected-by-innerhtml-after-ajax-call) for more info.

(N.B. A PHP script called via AJAX *could* make another HTTP request using something like `cURL` but it doesn't sound  like it would be helpful in the scenario you've described.)

---

It seems like your design should probably be something like:

File1.php is the one displayed in the browser. This should contain (or link to) all the JS code required for this feature.

File2.php is called via AJAX, and returns some data (perhaps in JSON format) and then the code in File1 builds some HTML and to display that data.

Then when the "change" event occurs on a specific `select`, some JS code (which is already loaded via File1) runs and makes the AJAX request to File3.